# Netplan, VLANs, and Nameservers (Where does all the info come from?)

Tags: network-manager, dns, netplan, vlan

I have netplan setup for one physical interface which in turn has a single vlan subinterface. Both the untagged interface and the vlan interface are statically addressed and have appropriate nameservers listed in the yaml file. My netplan config looks like this:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
        [ 192.168.51.7/24 ]
      gateway4: 192.168.51.1
      nameservers:
        search: [ my.domain ]
        addresses: [ 127.0.0.1, 192.168.51.8 ]
  vlans:
    IOTDevices:
      id: 4
      link: eno1
      addresses:
        [ 192.168.4.7/24 ]
      gateway4: 192.168.4.1
      nameservers:
        search: [ my.domain ]
        addresses: [ 127.0.0.1, 192.168.4.8 ]
```

This seems to generate a single file (IOTDevices.dhcp) in **/run/dhcpd/resolv.conf** which looks like this:

```
# Generated by dhcpcd from IOTDevices.dhcp
domain my.domain
search my.domain
nameserver 192.168.4.8
nameserver 192.168.4.7
```

This in turn seems to populate the **/etc/resolv.conf** file which looks like this:

```
# Generated by dhcpcd from IOTDevices.dhcp
# /etc/resolv.conf.head can replace this line
domain my.domain
nameserver 192.168.4.8
nameserver 192.168.4.7
# /etc/resolv.conf.tail can replace this line
```

I also see a file at **/etc/NetworkManager/no-stub-resolv.conf** which contains the IPs of both of the host's interfaces as well as the loopback address. All of these are valid nameservers as the host runs PiHole and Unbound.

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
search my.domain
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 192.168.51.8
nameserver 192.168.4.8
```

When I use dig to test DNS resolution, the response comes from 192.168.4.8 which is the first IP that appears in **/etc/resolv.conf**.

- Why does netplan generate a config file for the vlan subinterface, but nothing for the main interface? (The correct IP gets assigned, but the nameserver doesn't get added to **/etc/resolv.conf**).
- Is the information in the **/etc/NetworkManager/no-stub-resolv.conf** file being generated from the yaml file in **/etc/netplan**?
- How do I get the main interface's IP (192.168.51.7) or the loopback address (127.0.0.1) to show up in **/etc/resolv.conf** as the first nameserver?

Anything that points me in the right direction is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How did you come to have the dhcpcd package installed?  I'm seeing far too many questions from users whose system behavior is being broken by installing this universe package.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're using the NetworkManager renderer here, instead of the networkd default?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration file states at the top, "Generated by dhcpcd from IOTDevices.dhcp".  This is not part of netplan.  You have the `dhcpcd` package installed, which is not part of the default Ubuntu system, and does not integrate with netplan.  You should remove this package, as well as `resolvconf`,  which is also not part of the standard Ubuntu network stack.

Making these changes should result in /etc/resolved.conf being restored as a symlink to the systemd-resolved managed file under /run.